# Booting using usb flash 2.0 gives the boot error Acpi pcc probe failed

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb

I am trying to install 14.04.03 on my new Dell Inspiron 3542, it has 12.04.

Some how managed to prepare a bootable usb in 12.04 though was not a big deal. But I new to Ubuntu. Some how got a swap partition too. Now boot error:

```
[ 5.633316] ACPI PCC probe failed.
[ 7.059337] sd 2:0:0:0 [sdb] No caching mode page found.
[ 7.059389] sd 2:0:0:0 [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
```

Busybox v1. 21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu built in shell).

Can anyone suggest?

Comment: Are you sure you are booting from the USB drive? I'm running 14.04.1 LTS on Inspiron 3542 without any issues. Also, is your LTS version 32bit or 64bit? In case of 64bit, you must enable UEFI from bios settings for this to work.